# Highcharts annotations outside the plot area incorrectly placed

Tags: highcharts

I want to place annotations on the y-axis but outside of the plot area. These should be placed with a connector (callout) at the same height as the PlotLines.

However, the settings do not work correctly there (see image - the red one). The alignment should be horizontal 'right' and vertical 'centered'. So that the connector on the right side is on the axis.

[image: screenshot]

```
annotations: [{
labelOptions: {
  align: 'right',
  verticalAlign: 'middle',
  //distance: 0,
  overflow: 'allow',
  crop: false
},
labels: [{
  point: {
    x: -6,
    y: 273,
    yAxis: 0
  },
  format: 'wrong right middle'
}]
}]
```

Distance gives a wrong result. If activate this the annotation jumps to another position. It just seems to work for vertical displacement.
My current workaround is, I add a callout as css style. But this is not the way to go.

https://jsfiddle.net/xreality/dskfv986/

Thanks
Maik

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts annotations use `callout` symbol (`Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.callout`) by default which is not designed for this usage. However, you can modify it so that it fits your needs. Check my wrap posted below and demo with it.

Wrapper on `Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.callout` method:

```
(function(H) {
  H.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.callout = function(x, y, w, h, options) {
    var arrowLength = 6,
      halfDistance = 6,
      r = Math.min((options && options.r) || 0, w, h),
      safeDistance = r + halfDistance,
      anchorX = options && options.anchorX,
      anchorY = options && options.anchorY,
      path;

    path = [
      'M', x + r, y,
      'L', x + w - r, y, // top side
      'C', x + w, y, x + w, y, x + w, y + r, // top-right corner
      'L', x + w, y + h - r, // right side
      'C', x + w, y + h, x + w, y + h, x + w - r, y + h, // bottom-rgt
      'L', x + r, y + h, // bottom side
      'C', x, y + h, x, y + h, x, y + h - r, // bottom-left corner
      'L', x, y + r, // left side
      'C', x, y, x, y, x + r, y // top-left corner
    ];

    // Anchor on right side
    if (anchorX && anchorX > w) {

      // Chevron
      if (
        anchorY > y + safeDistance &&
        anchorY < y + h - safeDistance
      ) {
        path.splice(13, 3,
          'L', x + w, anchorY - halfDistance,
          x + w + arrowLength, anchorY,
          x + w, anchorY + halfDistance,
          x + w, y + h - r
        );

        // Simple connector
      } else {
        path.splice(13, 3,
          'L', x + w, h / 2,
          anchorX, anchorY,
          x + w, h / 2,
          x + w, y + h - r
        );
      }

      // Anchor on left side
    } else if (anchorX && anchorX < 0) {

      // Chevron
      if (
        anchorY > y + safeDistance &&
        anchorY < y + h - safeDistance
      ) {
        path.splice(33, 3,
          'L', x, anchorY + halfDistance,
          x - arrowLength, anchorY,
          x, anchorY - halfDistance,
          x, y + r
        );

        // Simple connector
      } else {
        path.splice(33, 3,
          'L', x, h / 2,
          anchorX, anchorY,
          x, h / 2,
          x, y + r
        );
      }

    } else if ( // replace bottom
      anchorY &&
      anchorY > h &&
      anchorX > x + safeDistance &&
      anchorX < x + w - safeDistance
    ) {
      path.splice(23, 3,
        'L', anchorX + halfDistance, y + h,
        anchorX, y + h + arrowLength,
        anchorX - halfDistance, y + h,
        x + r, y + h
      );

    } else if ( // replace top
      anchorY &&
      anchorY < 0 &&
      anchorX > x + safeDistance &&
      anchorX < x + w - safeDistance
    ) {
      path.splice(3, 3,
        'L', anchorX - halfDistance, y,
        anchorX, y - arrowLength,
        anchorX + halfDistance, y,
        w - r, y
      );
    } else { // add to support right arrows
        path.splice(13, 3,
          'L', x + w, anchorY - halfDistance,
          x + w + arrowLength, anchorY,
          x + w, anchorY + halfDistance,
          x + w, y + h - r
        );
    }

    return path;
  }
})(Highcharts);
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0eydz6q3/

**EDIT** 
For annotations that are dynamically added, we can use `chart.events.render` to get each element dimensions using `SVGElement.getBBox()` method and calculate appropriate offsets using particular annotation width and height. Nextly we have to remove the old annotations using `chart.removeAnnotations('id')` method and add new ones (with updated distance and x position) using `chart.addAnnotations(newOptions)`. Check the demo posted below.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        var chart = this,
          annotations = chart.annotations[0],
          options = annotations.userOptions,
          labels = options.labels,
          arrowWidth = 6,
          bbox;

        labels.forEach(function(label, i) {
          if (label.point.x === 0) {
            bbox = annotations.labels[i].getBBox();
            label.point.x = -(bbox.width / 2 + arrowWidth);
            label.distance = -bbox.height / 2;
          }
        });

        chart.removeAnnotation('annotations-id');
        chart.addAnnotation(options);
      }
    }
  }
```

Demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wf8q1odj/1/

Api reference: 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#getBBox
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#removeAnnotation
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addAnnotation

Comment: Thank you for your callout function. This will allow me to remove the css solution.

Unfortunately, it does not solve the real problem that the horizontal and vertical alignment does not work properly.
I expect the `verticalAlign: 'middle'` to center the annotation. You still have to specify `distance: -10`.
The same problem with the horizontal alignment that aligns with `align: 'right'` is NOT right. In your example, you must explicitly specify `x: -55`. Since I do not know how wide the box is (different text), the error-prone.

Nevertheless, thanks for your answer and example!
Maik

Comment: Here a revised view [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xreality/nrcy3oew/)

Comment: Unfortunately, Highcharts annotations `align` and `verticalAlign` works as you expect only within chart plot area. What you trying to achieve is out of annotations capability. So for your needs, you can create these plotLines annotations using SVGRenderer, plotLines.lables (with css styles) or annotations with a workaround I posted you in the answer (the edited part of the answer).